# NSWindowController showWindow Causes a Problem on Other Macs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I'm beta testing my new Mac App which works great on my two MacBook Pro's, and on one other beta tester's iMac. But with two other of my beta testers (both having the exact same osx as I do, 10.6.7) my app window won't open at launch.

Upon inspecting their console logs, I narrowed the problem down to the showWindow call on my class MainWindowController, a subclass of NSWindowController.

```
m_pMainWindowController= [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:MAIN_WINDOW_NIB_NAME];
[m_pMainWindowController showWindow:nil];
```

The showWindow call triggers all the viewController's awakeFromNib methods to be called and this all seems to happen correctly, but right before showWindow is to return, this message is sent to the console from my app:

```
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: number of objects (0) not equal to number of keys (2)
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: number of objects (0) not equal to number of keys (2)
```

I am finding this bug very hard to fix because I can't reproduce it on my Macs, and it doesn't appear to be originating in any of my code.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in a drawRect function. I was initializing a NSDictionary for font attributes, and did not check to see if a certain font was available to be loaded. Thus loading a nil into an NSDictionary. Classic noob mistake.